# How come my code says that the module socket is not callable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming

I am having this problem where python says that the module is not callable. I have tried using the method below as from module import module as the from module import*. all these say that the module is not callable. What am i doing wrong?

```
import socket
#creates socket
s = socket.socket()
port = 88
# binds socket to port
s.bind(('', port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
#establishes connection with client
c, addr = s.accept()
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have created the script naming it socket.py .
So the import tries to import itself because the name collision.

Comment: unfortunately the problem still persists, however it did reduce one error

Comment: Perhaps the socket.pyc is still there.